# link_to => undefined method path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created an object Events and I have refactored the controller. Now I have that :

The view :

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', event %></td>
```

The route :

```
scope 'admin', :module => 'back', :as => 'back' do
  root :to => 'events#index'
  resources :events
end
```

The controller :

```
class Back::EventsController < BackController
```

But I have an error undefined method event_path.
So I have changed the link with :

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', back_event %></td>
```

because when I make a rake routes I see that :

```
          back_event GET    /admin/events/:id(.:format)      back/events#show
                     PATCH  /admin/events/:id(.:format)      back/events#update
                     PUT    /admin/events/:id(.:format)      back/events#update
                     DELETE /admin/events/:id(.:format)      back/events#destroy
```

But now, I have the error :
undefined local variable or method `back_event

How can I create this link ?

Thanks.

Eric

Comment: Pass an `id` to the `show` action.Try this `<%= link_to 'Show', back_event_path(event) %>`.The show action expects an `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', back_event_path(event) %></td>
```

You really need to spend some time reading the basics: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html